# What is Macromedia Flash alternative in Ubuntu

Tags: flash

What is Macromedia Flash alternative in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean the Flash player (the browser plugin to play swf files) or the Macromedia Flash IDE (the application to produce swf files)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lightspark.

> Lightspark, is a free, open source Flash player. Lightspark is an
>   LGPLv3 licensed Flash player and browser plugin written in C++/C that
>   runs on Linux. It aims to support Adobe's newer Flash formats and AVM2
>   virtual machine.  The last released version is 0.6.0.1, download it
>   from [here](https://launchpad.net/lightspark).
>
> Lightspark currently supports YouTube well enough for daily use.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Lightspark](http://lightspark.github.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

gnash is an alternative Package details: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gnash

The homepage for gnash is: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Google Chrome Browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), it has a built-in Flash player that work very well and support all version of flash. You can play your flash in it or surf web using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. Quick, Brief and Precise:

1. **gnash** (open source alternative)
2. **flashplugin** (abobe)
3. **swfdec** (mozilla)

Answer (score -1):

use light spark as an alternative.
The required information is given in this screenshot.
[image]